# QGIS stopped working after updating it

Tags: qgis, installation

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I updated QGIS to 3.20.1-Odense (using `apt-get dist-upgrade` with repository listed on QGIS website) and now it won't start. QGIS (`/usr/bin/qgis.bin` actually) uses 100% CPU but nothing happens. The longest I have waited before terminating (using `CTRL-C`) is about 3 minutes. Details of my system are:

```bsh
~ $ /usr/bin/qgis --version 
QGIS 3.20.1-Odense 'Odense' (1c3c5cd677)


~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Does it sound like this: https://old.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/opiv56/heads_up_potential_update_problems_to_qgis_3201/

If so it's a bug they're working on. You may have to revert to an older version for the time being.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is adressed in [QGIS issue #44293](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44293) and <s>will be fixed with the 3.20.2 minor release</s> is getting fixed live:

- *Update as per comments:*

  [Windows builds have been fixed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/44343#issuecomment-885805060)

The suggested hotfix is to delete the `stylemetadata` relation in the `symbology-style.db` (Linux: `~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default`).

As always, take a backup!

Use the `sqlite3` CLI client, or a client like *DBeaver* to connect and drop that table.

Comment: BTW, it seems this only occurs with people with custom saved symbology in their default profile. So - for others seeing this - do this *if* you have a problem, not *in anticipation* of a problem.

Comment: Thank you @geozelot and @Houska! I renamed my `symbology-style.db` to `symbology-style.db.orig` and QGIS started working! It also created a new symbology-style.db! It is surprising that upon examining the `stylemetadata` table I found that is a single row with just a version number! Anyways, I appreciate both your help!

Comment: @Vijay glad it helped. More surprising to me is the fact that the *presence* (and not absence) of an now unused relation in a DB leads to an infinite loop in the code. Maybe an ORM setup issue with circular key references?

Comment: Update: Now fixed in the Windows distro - see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/44343#issuecomment-885805060

Comment: Thank you @Houska !